# Android - Dynamic text scaling for same dpi but different screen size

Tags: android, android-layout, dpi, screen-size

In my app I create multiple TextViews dynamically and the text size for each one I derive from the value stored in `dimens.xml` under values folder. On one hand I have the Nexus 4 and on the other hand I have Nexus 10. Both have the same "xhdpi" density bucket but one has the screen size of 4.7 inches and other has a screen size of 10.05 inches. I can have the same value for textsize due to their same density bucket but the text appearing fine on Nexus 4 appears too small on Nexus 10. How can I have my text appear appropriately large on such devices ? Let me know if any files need to be included.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing a lot more research I found out you can use both size and resolution specifiers together. I simply used `values-xlarge-mdpi` for Nexus 10 and `values-large-mdpi` for Nexus 4.

Answer (score 0):

In your dimens.xml file use **sp** instead of **dp**.

Before

```
 <dimen name="text_size">80dp</dimen>
```

After

```
 <dimen name="text_size">80sp</dimen>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create values-sw600dp and values-sw720dp and check in which one your tablet falls in. Set the dimension larger for the same key name in values-sw600dp and values-sw720dp based on your requirement.

Comment: can you tell me what do sw600 and sw720 represent ?

Comment: Go through this link https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html